# $resource service .success is not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, mongodb, angular-resource

I want to implement the login method with AngularJS, Node and MongoDB. I have built a Restful API where I send the request.

When I try to execute the GET request this error appears at the console `TypeError: UserService.logIn(...).success is not a function`

Succeess doesnt exist like the `$http` way?

I also found this but I cannot understand how to adjust it to fit my code.

- HTTP GET "class" actions: Resource.action([parameters], [success],
  [error])
- non-GET "class" actions: Resource.action([parameters], postData,
  [success], [error])
- non-GET instance actions: instance.$action([parameters], [success],
  [error])

**Service.js**

```
var appServices = angular.module('starter.services', ['ngResource']);

appServices.factory('UserService', function ($resource) {
    return {
        logIn: function (email, password) {
            return $resource("http://localhost:3000/users/login", {
                email: email,
                password: password
            });
        }
    }
});
```

**Controller.js**

```
    var apps = angular.module('starter.controller', []);
apps.controller('loginCtrl', function ($scope, $ionicPopup, $state, UserService) {

    $scope.doLogin = function doLogin(email, password) {


        if (email != null && password != null) {

            UserService.logIn(email, password).success(function (data) {
                $state.go('tabs.home');

            }).error(function (status, data) {

                var ionicPop = $ionicPopup.alert({
                    title: 'Login Failed',
                    template: 'Invalid email or password.\nPlease try again!'
                });
                console.log(status);
                console.log(data);
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: What's the point of using `$resource` here? Why not `$http`?

Comment: just look here in docs: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngResource/service/$resource

Comment: I think the .success() and .error() methods were deprecated. Use .then(successHandler, errorHandler) or .then(successHandler).catch(errorHandler) instead.

Comment: @ShaunScovil i tried this but then the error is the same as the previous but with then instead of success. I think the problem is with the parameters that i pass(email,password)

Comment: See my answer below. Typically, you would create an auth service that handles login/logout and, when the user is logged in, set a header with a token that can be passed to every other API endpoint call. So your `UserService` could be a resource configured to hit `http://localhost:3000/users/:userId` and you would call it after login, passing the current logged-in userId, like `UserService.get(userId);`.

Comment: I just updated my answer to illustrate how you can use `$resource` if you need to.

Answer (score 5):

The reason your `UserService.logIn()` method is not behaving as expected is, you are returning a new instance of `Resource` but never actually calling a method on it.

```
// This returns an instance of Resource, which is configured incorrectly.
// The second argument suggests that the URL has :email and :password
// parameters, which it does not. As a result, the email and password
// would be appended to the URL as query params (very insecure!).
return $resource("http://localhost:3000/users/login", {
    email: email,
    password: password
});
```

With $resource, you can define additional methods or modify the existing `get`, `save`, `query` and `delete` methods. However, this is only useful for API endpoints that support [CRUD operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete).

For a login call, you don't need to create a resource because you will not be performing CRUD operations. Use `$http` instead.

```
var appServices = angular.module('starter.services', ['ngResource']);

appServices.factory('authService', function ($http) {
    return {
        logIn: function (email, password) {
            return $http({
                url: 'http://localhost:3000/users/login',
                method: 'POST',
                data: {
                    email: email,
                    password: password
                },
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                withCredentials: true
            });
        }
    }
});
```

The above example assumes you want to pass the user credentials in the body of the request. This is *okay* assuming you are using SSL, but a preferred way would be to use an Authorization header. For example, [Basic Auth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) would be a bit more secure.

**UPDATE**

As it turns out, methods of `$resource` do not return a `Promise`. They return an instance of the resource, with a `$promise` property. So, you could for example do something like this:

```
// Using the .save() method, which performs a POST
$resource('http://localhost:3000/users/login').save({email: 'foo@bar.com', password: 'baz'})
    .$promise.then(handleSuccess, handleError);
```

Still, I recommend using `$http` for a login endpoint. However, if you need to use `$resource`, have a look at [this plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/hgUN93oVQs9CO6mEHebA?p=preview).